# Get Access form to display a property value from a custom class

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a MS Access Form and a Class.  The Class has a property: Cost

On the Code for the Form I have:

```vb
private clsMyClass as New MyClass
```

If on the Form I create a button with the code:

```vb
MsgBox clsMyClass.Cost  ' the value in cost is displayed
```

I want a Textbox to display this value.

I have tried putting `=clsMyClass.Cost` in the **Control Source** but I get a **#?NAME**

How can I display the value of my class property in a text box on my form?

Comment: Are you expecting this text box to reevaluate the class.Cost based on each record or do you just want to display a single value i.e. there is only one cost that is universal?

Comment: There is a general question here --- how to display a property from a custom class in a text box.  Closing this question on the basis of "too localized" would be ridiculous IMO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since Access doesn't cooperate with the class property as the text box control source, assign it's value during the form's On Current event.

This worked with Access 2007:

```vba
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit
Private clsMyClass As MyClass

Private Sub Form_Current()
    Me.txtCost = clsMyClass.Cost
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)
    Set clsMyClass = New MyClass
End Sub
```

Comment: My form doesn't have any records.  All of the fields are derived from values in the class and other functions in the form.  Can you suggest another Event?  OnCurrent seems to only fire when the underlying record changes.

Comment: My form which contains that code also doesn't have any records.  On Current fires as part of the standard sequence of events when you open a form, regardless of whether the form is bound or unbound.  With a bound form, On Current will fire *again* each time a different row becomes the current row ... but that doesn't apply in your case.